# form permanently write variable

Tags: php

So when the user clicks submit, I would like it to take the form inputs and permanently save them to a variable. I'm not to sure how this could be done, but I am aware of this method, but it doesn't save it permanently.

```
<?php
    $test = %_POST["example"];
?>

<form action="#" method="post">
    Example Input: <input type="text" name="example"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit"><br>
</form>
```

I then put

```
<?php echo $test ?>
```

which displayed my variable value, but as soon as the page is refreshed it's gone because of POST. How can I do something similar but when the page is refreshed it's still there?

I am open to other alternatives.

Comment: Code executes from scratch every time.  In order to save the variable "permanently" you would need to persist it somewhere outside of the context of the code.  There are many contexts from which to choose.  A database is a common choice.

Comment: Where did you came up with "permanently"? PHP executes a script and in that execution a global variable will retain its value, but once its finished its gone for good unless its stored in a db or other method

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `$_POST` variable lives only "per request", as you have already seen yourself when refreshing the page. 
You can however use sessions to keep the variable alive as long as the session lives. Or you save the data to a database and fetch the data again when requesting the page.

Regarding sessions, you would do that like this:

```
<?php

    session_start(); 
    if (isset($_POST['example'])) {
       $test = $_POST["example"];
       $_SESSION['formData'] = $test;
    }
    if (isset($_SESSION['formData'])) {
        echo $_SESSION['formData'];
    }

<?php
```

For more information and a simple tutorial see: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Comment: While this answer is valid, keep in mind that you should always handle user input data as a virus. For example, would we want our user to submit valid html data that includes the `<script>` tag? use `htmlentities()` for that, etc, etc.

Comment: @Xorifelse Thanks for pointing out that really important detail!